# Change scene after collision of different objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I have 10 cylinders in the sky and I want that when all 10 hit the ground (plane) I can change the scene to a different one.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 
 public class contactGround : MonoBehaviour
 {
     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
         if(col.gameObject.name == "Cylinder" && col.gameObject.name == "Cylinder (1)"
         && col.gameObject.name == "Cylinder (2)" && col.gameObject.name == "Cylinder (3)"
         && col.gameObject.name == "Cylinder (4)" && col.gameObject.name == "Cylinder (5)"
         && col.gameObject.name == "Cylinder (6)" && col.gameObject.name == "Cylinder (7)"
         && col.gameObject.name == "Cylinder (8)" && col.gameObject.name == "Cylinder (9)"){
             Debug.Log("Collision detected");
             SceneManager.LoadScene(16);  
         }
     }
 }
```

i try that but doesn't work. any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can one single object (`col.gameObject`) have 10 different names at the same time? ;)

You rather want to keep track of which objects collided and count how many have collided. Them once you reach 10 go to the next scene

```
public class contactGround : MonoBehaviour
{
    private HashSet<GameObject> collided = new HashSet<GameObject>();

     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
     {
         if(col.gameObject.name.StartsWith("Cylinder") && !collided.Contains(col.gameObject))
         {
             Debug.Log("Collision detected");
             collided.Add(col.gameObject);

             if(collided.Count >= 10)
             {
                 SceneManager.LoadScene(16); 
             } 
         }
     }
 }
```

Though in general rather do not go by me but give them a certain [Tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) like e.g. `Cyllinder` and then rather check

```
if(col.gameObject.name.CompareTag("Cylinder") && !collided.Contains(col.gameObject))
```